# "vagrant up" and VirtualBox Crashes Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v, vagrant

I'm trying to get a vagrant box for ubuntu and running on my windows machine, and every time I type in "vagrant up" I get a BSOD.
I've turned off Hyper-V in windows as this was the suggested fix. The issue is still there.

The error code I see in the VirtualBox logs is as follows:

```
00:00:05.633668          ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aCompo
nent={MediumWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

The file from a crash analysis is linked as follows:

[Pastebin link to crash analysis](https://pastebin.com/pXnNY5jg)

I'm currently running Virtualbox 5.2.2 and vagrant 2.0.1 on a Windows 10 machine.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Cheers

Comment: What d you mean you have tried turning off Hyper-V? What does your setup look like? Why Hyper-V and VirtualBox?

Comment: @Seth About Hyper-V, I've unchecked it as a feature in windows. Also what do you mean by setup? Are you referring to my hardware?

Comment: Do you have a minidump file under \windows\minidump\ from the bugcheck?  If so, maybe send it to http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze.  You could Pastebin the results and link it here.

Comment: @HelpingHand I've put up the link you requested. :)

Comment: I just want to say I have the same problem and will try to add my info here.

Comment: @Mateng. I found out that this is because Microsoft added Virtualization Based Security. Check out my answer for it

Comment: An update of Virtualbox to version 5.2.4, an update of my vagrant version to 2.0.4 AND an update of all vargrant plugins helped in my case:  `vagrant plugin update `

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Virtualization Based Security feature that Windows has from 1607 onwards.

Fix:

Check msinfo32.exe (System Information) and scroll to the bottom of your system summary. If you see "A hypervisor has been detected..." you're in secure mode and can't run other virtual environments without crashing windows.

Use an admin cli and type the following:

> reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard" /v "EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Restart the machine after this and check the system information again. 
You should see something like the following image:

[What you should see if it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFLPn.png)